# link doesn't print correctly after using \parentext tag using biblatex-chicago.sty

Tags: biblatex-chicago

My tags are follow:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}%

\bibliography{test.bib}

\begin{document}

But by this time a form of binary reckoning, without binary notation, had been detailed by John \citet{napierrad}, \textit{Rabdologi\ae} \parentext{English translation: \citet[649--749]{napierworks}}. In the final part of this work, ``Location Arithmetic,'' Napier details a  board-game style instrument for  numerical calculations, cautioning in the Preface: ``There is one small difficulty in working with it, and that is that the numbers it uses differ from ordinary numbers, so that one must begin by expressing ordinary numbers in the new form and end by reducing them to common form'' \citep[727]{napierworks}. In Napier's representation, each power of 2 is associated with a Roman letter---$a$ for 1, $b$ for 2, $c$ for 4, $d$ for 8, $e$ for 16, and so on---and numbers are written by concatenating the letters corresponding to  what we would now call the 1 bits in its binary representation. So $23=10111_2$, for example, would be written as $abce$, a form reminiscent of Roman numerals. Or to be precise, that would be the canonical representation of 23; any other sequence of letters that sum up to 23 would be equivalent---$abcdd$, for example, or $aaace$. These various forms of the same number could be derived from each other through mediation and duplation steps (replacing a $c$ by two $b$s or two $b$s by a $c$, for example). Napier's multiplication method involves labeling the bottom and right edges of a checkerboard $a$, $b$, $c$, \dots, putting tokens on the two margins to represent what we would call the binary notations for the two operands, putting a token at the intersection of any row and column that have tokens at the margin (the intersection square between the row representing $2^i$ and the column representing $2^j$ representing $2^{i+j}$), and finally accumulating at the bottom margin the tokens on each northeast-to-southwest diagonal (as all interior squares on such a diagonal have the same value of $i+j$ and hence represent the same power of 2). All that is left is to reduce the number represented by the piles of tokens on the bottom margin to canonical form---and then convert it back to decimal.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**test.bib**

```
@book{napierrad,
author={John Napier},
title={Rabdologiae},
address={Edinburgh},
publisher={Andreas Hart},
year={1617},
}

@book{napierworks,
author={Napier, John},
year={2017},
title={The Life and Works of John Napier},
editor={Brian Rice and Enrique Gonz\'alez-Velasco and Alexander Corrigan},
translator={Brian Rice and Enrique Gonz\'alez-Velasco and Alexander Corrigan},
address={Cham},
publisher={Springer},
}
```

**Output**

[image]

At the rounded place (red marked) the output should come as `(Napier 2017, 727)`, if I remove the tag `\parentext` then it works fine, please suggest what went wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-chicago`'s `authordate` behaviour is to just give the postnote (page number) for subsequent citations of the same work (for 'ibid.' citations).

This can be seen in

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, authordate]{biblatex-chicago}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite[381]{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite[12]{nussbaum}
sit \autocite[382]{sigfridsson}
amet \autocite[383]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, 380) ipsum (381) dolor (Nussbaum 1978, 12) sit (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, 382) amet (383)]

It is exactly the same in your case. In

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{napierrad,
  author    = {John Napier},
  title     = {Rabdologiae},
  address   = {Edinburgh},
  publisher = {Andreas Hart},
  year      = {1617},
}
@book{napierworks,
  author     = {Napier, John},
  year       = {2017},
  title      = {The Life and Works of John Napier},
  editor     = {Brian Rice and Enrique Gonz\'alez-Velasco and Alexander Corrigan},
  translator = {Brian Rice and Enrique Gonz\'alez-Velasco and Alexander Corrigan},
  address    = {Cham},
  publisher  = {Springer},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
But by this time a form of binary reckoning, without binary notation,
had been detailed by John \citet{napierrad}, \textit{Rabdologi\ae}
\parentext{English translation: \citet[649--749]{napierworks}}.
In the final part of this work, ``Location Arithmetic,''
Napier details a  board-game style instrument for  numerical calculations,
cautioning in the Preface:
``There is one small difficulty in working with it,
and that is that the numbers it uses differ from ordinary numbers,
so that one must begin by expressing ordinary numbers in the new form
and end by reducing them to common form'' \citep[727]{napierworks}.
Lorem \citep[728]{napierworks}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: But by this time a form of binary reckoning, without binary notation, had been detailed by John Napier (1617), Rabdologiæ (English translation: Napier [2017, 649–749]). In the final part of this work, “Location Arithmetic,” Napier details a board-game style instrument for numerical calculations, cautioning in the Preface: “There is one small difficulty in working with it, and that is that the numbers it uses differ from ordinary numbers, so that one must begin by expressing ordinary numbers in the new form and end by reducing them to common form” (727). Lorem (728).]

the `\citep[727]{napierworks}` follows `\citet[649--749]{napierworks}` (a citation of the same work), so slips into the "ibid." mode.

If this is not desired for this particular citation (because the previous citation to `\napierworks` was in parentheses), use `\mancite` to reset the citation tracker.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{napierrad,
  author    = {John Napier},
  title     = {Rabdologiae},
  address   = {Edinburgh},
  publisher = {Andreas Hart},
  year      = {1617},
}
@book{napierworks,
  author     = {Napier, John},
  year       = {2017},
  title      = {The Life and Works of John Napier},
  editor     = {Brian Rice and Enrique Gonz\'alez-Velasco and Alexander Corrigan},
  translator = {Brian Rice and Enrique Gonz\'alez-Velasco and Alexander Corrigan},
  address    = {Cham},
  publisher  = {Springer},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
But by this time a form of binary reckoning, without binary notation,
had been detailed by John \citet{napierrad}, \textit{Rabdologi\ae}
\parentext{English translation: \citet[649--749]{napierworks}\mancite}.
In the final part of this work, ``Location Arithmetic,''
Napier details a  board-game style instrument for  numerical calculations,
cautioning in the Preface:
``There is one small difficulty in working with it,
and that is that the numbers it uses differ from ordinary numbers,
so that one must begin by expressing ordinary numbers in the new form
and end by reducing them to common form'' \citep[727]{napierworks}.
Lorem \citep[728]{napierworks}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: But by this time a form of binary reckoning, without binary notation, had been detailed by John Napier (1617), Rabdologiæ (English translation: Napier [2017, 649–749]). In the final part of this work, “Location Arithmetic,” Napier details a board-game style instrument for numerical calculations, cautioning in the Preface: “There is one small difficulty in working with it, and that is that the numbers it uses differ from ordinary numbers, so that one must begin by expressing ordinary numbers in the new form and end by reducing them to common form” (Napier 2017, 727). Lorem (728).]

If you don't want this "ibid." function at all, disable it completely with `noibid`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber, noibid]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{napierrad,
  author    = {John Napier},
  title     = {Rabdologiae},
  address   = {Edinburgh},
  publisher = {Andreas Hart},
  year      = {1617},
}
@book{napierworks,
  author     = {Napier, John},
  year       = {2017},
  title      = {The Life and Works of John Napier},
  editor     = {Brian Rice and Enrique Gonz\'alez-Velasco and Alexander Corrigan},
  translator = {Brian Rice and Enrique Gonz\'alez-Velasco and Alexander Corrigan},
  address    = {Cham},
  publisher  = {Springer},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
But by this time a form of binary reckoning, without binary notation,
had been detailed by John \citet{napierrad}, \textit{Rabdologi\ae}
\parentext{English translation: \citet[649--749]{napierworks}\mancite}.
In the final part of this work, ``Location Arithmetic,''
Napier details a  board-game style instrument for  numerical calculations,
cautioning in the Preface:
``There is one small difficulty in working with it,
and that is that the numbers it uses differ from ordinary numbers,
so that one must begin by expressing ordinary numbers in the new form
and end by reducing them to common form'' \citep[727]{napierworks}.
Lorem \citep[728]{napierworks}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: But by this time a form of binary reckoning, without binary notation, had been detailed by John Napier (1617), Rabdologiæ (English translation: Napier [2017, 649–749]). In the final part of this work, “Location Arithmetic,” Napier details a board-game style instrument for numerical calculations, cautioning in the Preface: “There is one small difficulty in working with it, and that is that the numbers it uses differ from ordinary numbers, so that one must begin by expressing ordinary numbers in the new form and end by reducing them to common form” (Napier 2017, 727). Lorem (Napier 2017, 728).]

The difference between the solution is the behaviour of the last `\citep[728]{napierworks}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it works perfectly... Special thanks for your detailed explanation....